# Formatting a Quote

Tags: discussion

You can format quotes: is *this* right? or is "this" right?

In other words, would you say

*Like this* or "Like this"?

I sometimes edit to make the change to the first.

Comment: I voted up but still I don't understand what you are asking. Can you expand your example to be clear what "this" in "is *this* right" refers to?

Comment: @Theta30 Nothing really. Just filler text.

Comment: @Theta30 Like http://goo.gl/qB5sD5 vs http://i.imgur.com/ScQufqF.png

Comment: ok, I understand now. Note there is even a third possible variant I saw, "*cheerled*" i.e. Italics+quotations

Answer (score 8):

[Italic type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_type#When_to_use) has a few specific uses:

- Emphasis
- Titles, foreign words, and some names
- [Use-mention distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction), definitions, and examples
- Quoting thoughts (as opposed to speech or writing)
- Mathematical and scientific symbols

When quoting speech or writing, you should use quotation marks, **not** italics. When writing example phrases or sentences, you can use either.

I recommend against editing solely to adjust italic/quotation style, especially in the cases where either would be appropriate.

Comment: +1. I would also recommend against editing when one doesn't fully understand when either would be appropriate.

Comment: When quoting speech or writing in this site, there is the blockquote syntax `>` which is preferable to using quotation marks, **especially** for phrases and sentences.

Comment: @Andrew: 'preferable' by what criterion? Paragraphs, certainly: sentences, probably; phrases? How about "'preferable'" in my first sentence?

Comment: +1 @AndrewLeach It seems jarring to break the flow into chunks ( via > ) when quoting a phrase, be it short, anonymous, or both. For emphasis, however, doing so seems clearer (to me anyway).  @ TimL  You ask '"'preferable'"' about "'preferable'" in your first sentence, but I'm feeling too quotalacious (tm) now to answer... ;-P

Answer (score 2):

In writing about language and languages, there are more conventions to follow.
A short list of how a professional uses the formatting available here can be found
at the end of [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299).

Answer (score 0):

On this site, italics have a particular use, of mentioning the word rather than using it. If you want to know the etymology of the word *elephant* you don't, obviously, ask "What does elephant come from?" unless you want the answer "A mummy elephant". "What does "elephant" come from?" is not right either, since it refers to a quotation; presumably "Elephant!" came from somebody's unexpected meeting with an elephant. "What does 'elephant' come from?" is acceptable in normal speech, but on ELU there is more use of words-as-mention than most places, and also a divergence of opinion about straight quotes or curly quotes (as [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/535/8019)), so the usual wording is "what does *elephant* come from?"  This isn't as common in the outside world, though it's by no means unusual.

Comment: I suppose this level of detail is down to personal preference, but I would never italicise ‘elephant’ in that context: I would put it in single, curly quotes. Double quotes = direct quote; single quotes = word-as-mention; italics = non-English word (or reconstructed forms); italics in double quotes = directly quoting a non-English word; italics in single quotes = non-English word-as-mention. The latter two are, admittedly, fairly rare.

Answer (score -3):

In my experience, quote marks if you know and can identify the author. Italics are fine for titles and unattributable sayings.